# Tarea periódica en C

Tags: c

Tengo este problema de productor/consumidor: Existe un único productor y consumidor con un búfer compartido circular con la implementación clásica del problema basada en **semáforos**.

La idea es hacer que una hebra controle los dos procesos periódicamente. Lo intenté primero con la tarea del productor para que produzca cada 1 segundo, o sea al productor se le avisa de que tiene que producir cada segundo, pero me sale un error que no consigo entender:

> referencia a `timer_create` sin definir, referencia a `timer_settime` sin definir

Éste es el código:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#define MAXT 10

int array[MAXT];
int nelem=0;
int puedo=1;
sem_t hayespacio,haydato,mutex;

void *producir(void * argg){
int dato;
int p=0,i=0;
while(1){   
    while(puedo){
    dato=rand()%20;
    sem_wait(&hayespacio);
    sem_wait(&mutex);

    while(nelem==MAXT);
        array[p]=i;
        printf(" P: %d %d\n",array[p],p);
        if(p==MAXT-1){
            p=0;
        }
        else{
            p=p+1;
        }
        i++;
    nelem++;
    sem_post(&mutex);
    sem_post(&haydato);
    puedo=0;
  }
 }
}
void *consumir(void *argg){
int c=0;

while(1){
    sem_wait(&haydato);
    sem_wait(&mutex);
    while(nelem==0);
        printf("C: %d \n",array[c]);
        if(c==MAXT-1){
            c=0;
        }
        else{
            c=c+1;
        }
    nelem--;
    sem_post(&mutex);
    sem_post(&hayespacio);
 }  
}
void *periodic (void *arg) {

struct itimerspec required, old;
struct timespec first, period;
struct sigevent sig; /* información de señal */
int signum; /* señal recibida */
sigset_t set;
timer_t timer;

// Asociamos señal y temporizador
sig.sigev_notify = SIGEV_SIGNAL;
sig.sigev_signo = SIGALRM;
sig.sigev_value.sival_ptr = &timer;
first.tv_sec = first.tv_sec + 3;
period.tv_sec = 1;
period.tv_nsec = 0;
required.it_value = first;
required.it_interval = period;

if (clock_gettime (CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &first) != 0) error();
if (timer_create(CLOCK_MONOTONIC,&sig,&timer) != 0)
error();
if (sigemptyset(&set) != 0) error ();
if (sigaddset(&set, SIGALRM) != 0) error();
if (timer_settime(timer,0, &required, &old) != 0)
error ();
while (1) {
if (sigwait(&set, &signum) != 0) error();
puedo=1;
}
}
int main(){
pthread_t pro,con,th1;
pthread_attr_t attr;
int i;
sem_init(&hayespacio,0,10);
sem_init(&haydato,0,0);
sem_init(&mutex,0,1);

pthread_attr_init(&attr);

pthread_create(&th1,&attr,periodic,NULL);

pthread_create(&pro,&attr,producir,NULL);
pthread_create(&con,&attr,consumir,NULL);

pthread_join(pro,NULL);
pthread_join(con,NULL);

}
```

Comment: Tienes que incluir time.h:  #include <time.h>

Comment: la libreria time.h ya esta incluida en #include <sys/time.h>.(lo he incluidootra vez para probar pero sigue igual).

Comment: Supuestamente esta ahí, ponla explícitamente. He supuesto que   ei error es al momento de  compilar no en la  vinculación.

Comment: ya encontre el origen del error. tenia que enlazar la libreria al compilar asi que he añadido el comando -lrt. pero ahora resulta que mi programa se queda atrapado en elgun bucle y no se cual es aunque lo he buscado.

Comment: se queda atrapado en el bucle del productor esperando que la hebra periodic le de permiso para producir pero lo que pasa es que periodic no se ejecuta.

Comment: Si vas a poner un thread que controle a los otros 2, entonces , este debe tener un semáforo de iespera para el productor y otro para el consumidor . Tanto el productor como el consumidor debe esperar estos semáforos para poder arrancar con el.proceso y el thread periodic debe ser el último en levantarse, total los otros dos van a esperar a este para poder continuar.  Las esperas trata de no hacerlas con un loop while esperando el cambio de valor de la variable porque puede que esté while tomo todo el recurso de cpu y no deje continuar a otros, aunque ahora hay más procesadores.

Comment: Por lo mismo que hay más procesadores pueden ejecutarse en paralelo. Trata de usar los semáforos o variables de condicion para sincronizar desde el otro thread.

Comment: Podrias ajustar tu código en base a esto y quizás abrir otra entrada y cerrar este.porque en verdad el problema por el que se abrió ya se le dio solución. Pon 5u comentario como solución.

Comment: Y eso del while variable pasa con el productor que apenas arranca la variable puedo esta en 1 la cambia a 0 y entra a un loop while(1) y por lo menos se tira un procesador. El periodic lo pone en 1 hace y entra en otro loop terrible. A parte cada vez quevperiodic le de paso albproductor este llena los 10 buffers o solo 1 hasta el siguiente segundo. Ojo que periodic debe esperar que terminen para iniciar la espera de otro segundo

Comment: El uso de un semaforo es una mejor idea. aunque el problema siguio alli porque me parecio que la tarea peridic le faltaba algo ya no se ejecutaba periodicamente. se queda esperando en el sigwait.  asi que use periodic con reloj en vez de timer.

Comment: con un semaforo para el Prod y otro para el Cons y un reloj se consigue el comportamiente deseado aunque me gustaria saber que es lo que faltaba en el periodic con temporizador.

Comment: Te sirvió nibcomentario? Parabponerlo como respuesta.

Comment: Si.Gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: Ok. Voy a escribir  la respuesta en base a  nuestros comentarios. Adicionalmente, si mis pruebas lo confirman, adicionó  lo que le falta a los temporizadores para que funcionen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema puede deberse a dos cosas:

1. Si se produce durante la compilación es porque la cabecera 
   time.h no está incluida o incluida en un lugar incorrecto.
2. Si se produce durante la vinculación es porque no has 
   referenciado a la libreria.

Tengo algunas observaciones y recomendaciones sobre cómo has implementado el problema producto consumidor ambos controlados un thread.

1. Lo primero que te recomiendo es que no utilices variables para
   sincronizar threads. Quizá funcionaba bien  cuando los computadores
   solo tenían un procesador. Ahora tienen más de uno y te va a causar
   problemas. En su lugar utiliza variables condicionales que utilizan
   notificaciones para sincronizar threads. Esto es con respecto a cómo
   "periódic" le dice productor que arranque.
2. Estás utilizando un complicado sistema de alarma solo con el
       propósito de esperar 60 segundos. Para ello es mejor que dentro del
       bucle  while tengas un sleep(60000).
3. "periódic" deberá sincronizarse con el productor para arrancar el  proceso y también sincronizarse con el consumidor puesto que este   debe iniciar un huevo ciclo de espera cuando finalice este.